# Automate git commit message formatting regardless of editor

Tags: git, sed, vim, posix, text-formatting

I use vim to write my commit messages, which means they get formatted "the right way" automatically. That is, as I write, my messages are formatted more or less as described in the classic article ["A Note About Git Commit Messages"](https://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html) (hard wraps at 72 columns, indented list). You'll probably see this referenced as a "good" format for commit messages (together with writing stuff in the imperative mood).

However, I work with people who don't use vim, so I'd like to enforce that their commit messages are "correctly" formatted. In general, I don't want the format of commit messages to depend on what editor you choose to write your commit message in. I also sometimes might want to write commit messages from e.g. Visual Studio Code.

It seems like a smarter idea to just automatically format the commit message   (like running `prettier` on *code*, but for commit messages).

I've tried to achieve this with a `commit-msg` hook (managed using [`lefthook`](https://github.com/evilmartians/lefthook/tree/master)), but I cannot figure out how to write the hook to format the commit message.

My question has 2 parts:

- What's a good way to enforce a consistent format for commit messages, if not to reformat in a `commit-msg` hook? Note that I think formatting is preferable to just validating the format.
- What's a simple, portable way to format a commit message according to this preferred format? Is there e.g. a simple `sed` script that could be used instead? FWIW, I've also tried `prettier`, treating the message as Markdown, but that... has other issues.

I've tried to run vim in batch mode, because I figured I'm basically trying to do `gqG`. This doesn't work as-is, though, because (1) `gqG` also formats the `#` lines that are typically part of a commit message and (2) I can't get it to work in `Ex` mode.

Basically, here's my non-working hook script:

```bash
INPUT_FILE=$1

vim --clean -es -c 'set filetype=gitcommit' -c 'g/^#/d' -c '%norm! gqG' -c "write" -c "quit" $INPUT_FILE
```

This gets rid of the comments (`g/^#/d`), but `%norm! gqG` isn't doing what I except. I've also tried `g/^/norm gqq`, but this creates different results.

Possible alternatives to vim:

- `fmt`: With GNU fmt, `fmt -t -w 72` gets pretty close, but it doesn't work for list items that aren't paragraphs (so if a list is `- item 1\n- item 2` it gets formatted into a single paragraph). Of course, if you're on a Mac, you get BSD `fmt` by default which behaves differently.
- `fold`: Too simple. Doesn't handle lists or trailers correctly.
- `par`: I don't know how to configure this correctly.
- `prettier`: Does not format git trailers correctly.

A combination of splitting commit messages by paragraph and formatting them individually might work (using `sed` or `awk`?).

Comment: Are you sure you want your hook to depend on some specific version of Vim (`--clean` is a recent addition)?

Comment: @romainl Obviously, it'd be better if it's as universal as possible :) Seems it was added in 8.0.0716 released in 2017, which I'm fine with. That said, it seems like `--clean` is more or less the same as `-u DEFAULTS -U NONE -i NONE`, so I guess that's preferable (going by the documentation).

Comment: People will find ways to break whatever formatting tools you throw at them. Educate your coworkers or live with them.

Comment: @Friedrich I've updated the title of the question to better reflect that this is about automating the formatting of commit messages, regardless of editor.

Comment: Thanks for improving your question. I don't think you got my criticism, however. The first line of the model commit message reads "Capitalized, short (50 chars or less) summary". What if not? You can hard-wrap at column 51, add a blank line and render the message hard to understand. Even worse, what if they describe the problem they solve first and their changes afterwards? What if they stuff multiple changes into one commit and describe them one after the other? These are problems likely to occur and beyond a formatting tool. It is a noble pursuit.

Comment: @Friedrich As you say, those issues go beyond formatting, so they're not really relevant for my question. The question is about automating formatting without requiring a specific editor.